Brun's sieve: There are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ has at most $20$ prime factors
This is exercise 2 (p. 120) of chapter 6 in Iwaniec-Kowalski's book "Analytic number theory". More specifically, let $\pi_2(x, z)$ denote the number of primes $p\leq x$ for which $p+2$ has no prime divisors $<z$. Then the exercise asks to prove
$$
\pi_2(x, x^{1/20})\gg x(\log x)^{-2}.
$$
I don't know if I am supposed to just use Corollary 6.2, but there are no stronger results in that section of the book. This result is somewhat complicated, so it is possible that I'm misinterpreting something. I try to state it below.
Corollary 6.2. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers. Let $\mathcal P$ be a set of primes, and put
\begin{align*}
 P(z)&=\prod_{\substack{p< z\\ p\in \mathcal P}} p\\
 S(x, z)&=\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ (n, P(z))=1}}a_n\\
 A_d(x)&=\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\ n\equiv 0\mod d}} a_n.
\end{align*}
Suppose that there exists a multiplicative function $g$ such that for $d$ squarefree with all prime factors in $\mathcal P$,
$$
 A_d(x)=g(d)X+r_d(x)
$$
with $X=X(x)$ independent of $d$. Suppose further that $g(p)\in [0,1)$ for $p\in \mathcal P$; $g(p)=0$ for $p\not\in \mathcal P$; and that there exist constants $K>1$ and $\kappa>0$ such that
$$
 \prod_{w\leq p< z}(1-g(p))^{-1}\leq K\left(\frac{\log z}{\log w}\right)^\kappa
$$
for any $w<z$. Define
\begin{align*}
 V(z)&=\prod_{p\mid P(z)}(1-g(p))\\
 R(x, y ; z)&=\sum_{\substack{d<y\\ d\mid P(z)}} |r_d(x)|\tag{!}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
 S(x, z)&<(1+e^{\beta-s}K^{10})V(z)X+R(x, z^s; z)\tag{!!}\\
 S(x, z)&>(1-e^{\beta-s}K^{10})V(z)X-R(x, z^s; z),
\end{align*}
where $\beta=9\kappa+1$ and $s$ is any number $\geq \beta$.
Iwaniec-Kowalski define the function $R$ of (!) in equation (6.24), but they just write
$$
R(x, y)=\sum_{\substack{d<y\\ d\mid P(z)}}|r_d(x)|.
$$
My interpretation is that this is an abuse of notation and that this function depends on three variables $x,y,z$, and thus it is more appropiate to write $R(x, y; z)$. (!!) is also problematic for this reason, since they just write $R(x, z^s)$, but I'm interpreting it as $R(x, z^s; z)$.
We want to apply the corollary to the case where $(a_n)$ is defined by
$$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
1\,\,\text{if}\,\,n=p+2\\
0\,\,\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
and $\mathcal P$ is the set of all primes. Note that $\pi_2(x, x^{1/20})=S(x, x^{1/20})$. In this setting, we have
$$
A_d(x)=\sum_{\substack{p\leq x-2\\ p \equiv -2\mod d}}1=\pi(x-2; d, -2)=\frac{li(x)}{\varphi(d)}+O(\varepsilon(x)),
$$
where $li(x)=\int_2^x\frac{1}{\log u}du$ and $\varepsilon(x)$ will keep track of the error, uniformly in $d$. Thus we can take $X=li(x)$, $r_d(x)=O(\varepsilon(x))$, and $g(d)=\frac{1}{\varphi(d)}$. $g$ is clearly multiplicative and $g(p)\in [0,1)$ for all primes except $p=2$. But that's okay, we can just set $g(2)=0$ (so that $g(n)=0$ if $n$ is even). I believe Merten's theorem (see Montgomery-Vaughan Theorem 2.7 (e)) implies that
$$
\prod_{2<p<x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p-1}\right)^{-1}=C\log x+O(1)
$$
for some constant $C$. In particular, there exists some $K>1$ with
$$
\prod_{w\leq p<z}\left(1-\frac{1}{p-1}\right)^{-1}\leq K\frac{\log z}{\log w},
$$
for any $w,z$ with $2<w<z$. Thus, $\kappa=1$ and $\beta=10$. We also have
\begin{align*}
V(z)&=\prod_{2<p<z}\left(1-\frac{1}{p-1}\right)=\frac{1}{C\log z}+O\left(\frac{1}{\log^2 z}\right)\\
R(x, y; z)&=O(\varepsilon(x))\sum_{\substack{d<y\\ d\mid P(z)}}1.
\end{align*}
Putting all of this together and using the corollary, we have
$$
S(x, x^\gamma)>\frac{\gamma(1-e^{10-s}K^{10})}{C}\frac{li(x)}{\log x}+O\left(\frac{li(x)}{\log^2 x}\right)+O(\varepsilon(x))\sum_{\substack{d<x^{\gamma s}\\ d\mid P(x^\gamma)}}1.
$$
We would like to choose $\gamma=1/20$ and $s\geq 10$ so that $1-e^{10-s}K^{10}>0$. In that case, the term which is $O(li(x)/\log^2 x)$ is negligible. A generalized Riemann hypothesis allows us to take $\varepsilon(x)=\sqrt x\log x$. However, I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that $\sum_{\substack{d<x^{\gamma s}\\ d\mid P(x^\gamma)}}1\asymp x^{\gamma s}$. Thus, we would need that $\gamma s+\frac 12<1$, but if $\gamma=1/20$ this means $s<10$, which is not possible. In any case, $\sum_{\substack{d<x^{\gamma s}\\ d\mid P(x^\gamma)}}1\gg x^\gamma$ and so we would need $x^\gamma \varepsilon(x)$ to be negligible compared with $li(x)/\log x$, but I don't think we have that strong unconditional error terms.
Conclusion: So assuming the (conditional) error term $\varepsilon(x)=\sqrt x \log x$ I can only prove that $\pi_2(x, x^\gamma)\asymp x(\log x)^{-2}$ for some small $\gamma<1/20$.
